# Navigation between months in CalendarView

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, calendarview

When I drag and drop a CalendarView in my activity, it seems that user can see just current month and navigate between months by clicking on right and left arrows, exactly what I want.

[image]

But when I run the app in my phone, something different happens. The current month is shown on top of the page and next months are visible after that. Also navigation between months will be done by scrolling up and down.

[image]

Why it happens and what should I do if I want a UI like the first kind of calendar? Is there any way to change attributes or do something to achieve this UI? I searched a lot for customization, but I just found some solutions that use table and gridview to make a whole calendar by theirselves.

Furthermore I want to create a Persian calendar. Is it possible to change this gregorian calendar to a Persion one or I can't use this widget at all?

Notice that I have to implement this by my self, so I can't use any provided libararies or components created by some developers else.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE1**

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="reyhan.test.MainActivity">

<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE2**

I noticed that this issue probably just happens on android 5.1.1 . It works properly on android 6 and it looks like below picture on android 4.4 .

[image]

How can I make it compatible to all devices that are higher than API 14? (I choosed API14 for min SDK at the first of creating my project.)

Comment: Are screen resolution, size and ppi on your phone the same as in emulator?

Comment: It does not happen to me. Please add the xml codes of your layout to your question

Comment: I don't know. How could I find out? If they're not same, how can I fix it and make it compatible with all devices? @Alex.S

Comment: I added it. @MatinLotfaliee

Comment: It still does not happen to me.